# How do I cite Blender builds/release correctly for Publications using Bibtex?

Tags: versions, documentation

I am writing articles and would like to cite Blender correctly. How should I do this?

**EDIT**

If you run R, and type `citation()`, you would get the following instantly;

```
 @Manual{,
    title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
    author = {{R Core Team}},
    organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
    address = {Vienna, Austria},
    year = {2013},
    url = {http://www.R-project.org/},
  }
```

And you can put this in Bibtex and cite R correctly. Is there an equivalent way of doing this in Blender to get an official/correct citation?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/8743/how-to-cite-software-in-latex

Comment: @stacker Thanks for the link. Do I need to use `Edition` entry for Blender as well? Where do I put Ton's name?

Comment: I had to follow rules when writing a thesis, but most of the work was done by a tool (https://www.zotero.org/). I would compare the citation style with a PhD thesis submitted at the institute.

Comment: So, how do I find citation style of a PhD thesis submitted at the institute? Is there a free copy I can download?

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that you're writing articles and not a thesis, with institute I meant the university (not the blender institute). In your case you could compare other articles published there (where you plan to publish).

Comment: I looked into ACM and the citation to Blender is somewhat inconsistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender has no functionality to do this, but you could use a Python script.

```
def citation():
    import bpy

    build_year = bpy.app.build_date.partition(b'-')[0].decode('ascii')

    return '''\
@Manual{,
   title = {Blender - a 3D modelling and rendering package},
   author = {{Blender Online Community}},
   organization = {Blender Foundation},
   address = {Blender Institute, Amsterdam},
   year = {%s},
   url = {http://www.blender.org},
 }''' % build_year

# test to see it works:
print(citation())
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the entries for author and address.

Answer (score 2):

You can cite Blender as any other software. There are also some books about Blender that you can cite. Some possible citations are here http://www.citebay.com/how-to-cite/blender/